# Make each data point its own mark in ggplot2 bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm recreating a series of graphs and charts for the automation of a report in ggplot in R, one of which is the below chart. The original chart had every data point as it's own mark (I'm sure there's a better way to say this but I cannot think of it at the moment, apologies), I'm fairly certain I've seen something similar years ago but again I can't remember. Is there any function/argument in ggplot that will allow me to change the first chart to the second.

My current graph;
[image: My current graph]

My desired output (please forgive the awful attempt in paint);
[image: My desired output]

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(person = c("staff", "staff", "customer", "staff", "customer", "customer", "customer", "staff", "customer", "staff"),
                 date = c("August", "August", "September", "September", "September", "October", "October", "October", "October", "November"))
```

Example code:

```
    figure1 <-
  df %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(
      x = date, 
      fill = person),
    col = "black"
  ) %>%
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "1 month",
    date_labels = "%b"
  )
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would think `geom_col(color = "black", fill = aes(group))` would do it, where `group` is whatever variable gives the 2 fill colours in your example plot. Some example data and code would help.

Comment: Have added a small data and code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an out-of-the-box function in ggplot2 that does this for you, but the downside of `stat_bin()` is that it summarises the data, while you'd have to skip this summarisation step for your histogram.

Here is a helper function that assigns bins to observations that you can use with `geom_col()`. I also added a histogram in yellow to show that the outlines are the same.

```r
library(ggplot2)

binwidth <- 0.1

# Helper function for histogram
assign_bin <- function(x, binwidth = 0.1) {
  cuts <- seq(min(x) - binwidth, 
              max(x) + binwidth, 
              by = binwidth)
  cuts[findInterval(x, cuts)]
}

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_col(
    aes(x = assign_bin(Sepal.Width, binwidth), 
        y = 1,
        fill = Species),
    width = binwidth,
    colour = "black",
    position = "stack"
  ) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(Sepal.Width),
    binwidth = 0.1,
    fill = NA,
    colour = "yellow"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I didn't end up needing the function (possibly because my full code I used time series axis? not sure), but the solution you gave worked perfectly. I was using a geom_bar, but changed to geom_col and adding the histogram was the solution. Thanks!